# Re-fix the drywall patch after painting

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall

This is my first time patching the drywall (external). After I painted, the border of the patch is showing up. Wondering how to fix this now.

I applied paper tape and drywall compound (three coats) and then sanded and applied primer and re-sanded. I did see some border due to the compound and primer but ignored and proceeded with paint.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix paint after patching holes in the wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/178225/how-to-fix-paint-after-patching-holes-in-the-wall)

Comment: Or this? [How do I fix this HORRIBLE drywall patch?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/205324/how-do-i-fix-this-horrible-drywall-patch)

Comment: Or this? [Fixing patch up that has gotten 1st coat of paint](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/194642/fixing-patch-up-that-has-gotten-1st-coat-of-paint)

Comment: Or this? [How can I repair a poor drywall taping job?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/63753/how-can-i-repair-a-poor-drywall-taping-job)

Comment: A strong light source at a very low angle is magic.

Comment: Sunny, feel free to edit your question and ask follow up questions to any of the above suggested answers, or just upvote the answer(s) that worked for you.